# Site becomes slow on traffic spikes but no load on server

Tags: linux, centos7, lamp

Excuse me for my limited server knowledge

I run a website on a Centos LAMP dedicated server, Core i7 with 32 GB RAM on a 1 GBPS line with 2 TB Traffic quota... when traffic goes up (bout 600+ users as per Google Analytics) the site becomes unavailable or becomes too slow. I checked the server load, but it shows

```
 1 user,  load average: 0.33, 0.37, 0.39
Tasks: 406 total,   1 running, 405 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.5 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.8 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32463380 total, 16733848 free,  7890424 used,  7839108 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777084 total, 16777084 free,        0 used. 23906928 avail Mem
```

The site setup is very simple, just one Wordpress and One Mybb forum installation

What might be causing the bottleneck ?

Any help is really appreciated ...

Comment: Check your system logs, your web server error logs, your PHP logs, your network usage, and any other logs you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably hit the `MaxClients` and `ServerLimit` limit of apache. Default is 256 you have 600. This puts clients to a queue to keep server load low. You need to edit httpd.conf and increase limit. Name of the variable may vary depending your Apache version. Also don't forget to restart apache after change.

The `MaxClients` directive was the name for `MaxRequestWorkers` directive before version Apache 2.3.13

For Apache version 2.4.6 you may find these settings in

```
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
```

Comment: Thats a great tip... but I scanned the entire httpd.conf file and couldn't find any variables like that.... My  Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS 7) can you please suggest where I can find that directives ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Added the config file location

Comment: Nailed it.... and now it works fine .... thanks a lot for your kind help

Comment: @BijuMathew glad it worked. I'd really appreciate if you accept my answer by ticking on the left